# VB.net -- Creating an instance of an assembly

Tags: vb.net, exception, dll, instance

I am trying to run a .dll and create an instance of it, but I am getting this error:

*Error  1   Value of type 'System.Reflection.Assembly' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Byte'.*

---

My code:

```
Public NotInheritable Class method
    Private Sub method_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Try
            Dim dll() As Byte = Assembly.Load("data.dll")
            Dim a = Assembly.Load(dll)
            Dim b As Type = a.GetType("data.Class1")
            Dim c As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(b)
            b.InvokeMember("main", BindingFlags.Default Or BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, c, Nothing)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Caught: {0}", ex.Message)

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
The main sub in the .dll includes "MsgBox("Success")", so it should definitely show me something if it worked correctly.

If I skip the dll to byte line and Dim a to Assembly.Load("data.dll"), it gives me the error that it can't be opened as Type integer of something like that.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Alright, my first question was answered, however. My new one is very similar:

```
    Try
        Dim g As New Net.WebClient()
        Dim dll() As Byte = g.DownloadData("http://ge.tt/api/1/files/6YVzYRI2/0/blob?download")
        Dim a = Assembly.Load(dll)
        Dim b As Type = a.GetType("data.Class1")
        Dim c As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(b)
        b.InvokeMember("main", BindingFlags.Default Or BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, c, Nothing)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Caught: {0}", ex.Message)

    End Try
```

With the link leading to my data.dll.
Is the reason still the same why it doesn't work?
And how am I able to fix it?

Comment: Note: you dont create an instance of an assembly, nor do you run a dll.  The code is trying to instance `Class1` in the assembly

Comment: I'm not really sure what I am doing, but I do know the code is correct, just not working. And I am wondering why.. :(

Comment: It is better to open up a new questions if you have a second one. It would be unfair for sloth since he answered your first question but someone else could answer your second.

Comment: @the_lotus Don't worry, I also answered the follow up question, since it was closely related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write:

```
Dim dll() As Byte = Assembly.Load("data.dll")
```

but `Assembly.Load` does not return a Byte array, but an instance of the `Assembly` class (that's exactly what the error message tells you).

---

Also note that when you use [`Assembly.Load(assemblyString As String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ky3942xh(v=vs.110).aspx), the method expects the (long form of the) assembly name, not the file name; something in the form of

```
"SampleAssembly, Version=1.0.2004.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8744b20f8da049e3"
```

---

If you want to load an assembly by its path, you could use [`Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFile As String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

To load the type `Class1`, you have to specify full name of the type (namespace + class name):

```
Dim b As Type = a.GetType("Class1.Class1")
```

The namespace is `Class1`, and the class name is also  `Class1`, so you have to use `Class1.Class1`.

Comment: If I skip the dll to byte line and Dim a to Assembly.Load("data.dll"), it gives me the error that it can't be opened as Type integer of something like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!! I understand a little better now already. :) 
I added one last question to my.. question.

Could you take a look at it also?